# Running the base monad of a pipe

Tags: haskell, pipe

Having the following stateful consumer:

```
consumer1 :: Consumer a (StateT b m) ()
```

What is the optimal way to convert it to the following one with the help of `execStateT`?

```
consumer2 :: Consumer a m b
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does it have to be `execStateT` ? It can be done easier with [`runStateP`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.2/docs/Pipes-Lift.html#g:5) from [`Pipes.Lift`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.2/docs/Pipes-Lift.html).

```
import Pipes
import Pipes.Lift
import Control.Monad.State.Strict

-- unnecessarily specific signature, function work with any Proxy
foo :: Monad m => b -> Consumer a (StateT b m) () -> Consumer a m b
foo b p = liftM snd $ runStateP b p
```

The functions in `Pipes.Lift` are great when you have a pipeline for which different stages have different effects. It's better to limit an effect to the specific stage of the pipeline on which is needed.

Comment: Great! There actually exists [an `execStateP` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.2/docs/Pipes-Lift.html#v:execStateP). Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I forgot about `execStateP`. Even simpler, then.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [execStateP](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.2/docs/Pipes-Lift.html#v:execStateP) in [`Pipes.Lift`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.2/docs/Pipes-Lift.html) mentioned by danidiaz.

```
execStateP :: Monad m => s -> Proxy a' a b' b (StateT s m) r -> Proxy a' a b' b m s
```

edit:

In general if the base monad is an `MFunctor` you can use the `distribute` function to bring the base monad to the top of the stack, then you can "run" the monad it eliminating that monad layer.

```
distribute
  :: (Monad m, Monad (t m), Monad (t (Proxy a' a b' b m)),
      MonadTrans t, MFunctor t) =>
     Proxy a' a b' b (t m) r -> t (Proxy a' a b' b m) r
```

Using `execStateT` as an example:

```
> :t S.execStateT . distribute 
S.execStateT . distribute
  :: Monad m =>
     Proxy a' a1 b' b (S.StateT s m) a -> s -> Proxy a' a1 b' b m s
```

The `MFunctor` restriction can be lifted if you define your monad stack carefully.  So for example with a carefully defined monad stack with a pipes layer on each side of a continuation layer you can define a `distributeCont` which will work with the continuation transformer, which is not a `MFunctor`.